# HTTP Get file from different site and return with Express for download

Tags: node.js, express, fs

I'm trying to download a file from another site from my Node app after an express HTTP get request and then return the file for download. I've tried multiple ways of getting the file, using pipe, blob, etc. but I'm grasping in the dark. The code might give you a bit more of an insight as to what I'm trying to achieve:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');

router.get('/download/:file', function (req, res, next) {
  http.get('http://anothersite/' + req.params.file, function(response) {
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + req.params.file);
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/octet-stream');
    res.download(fs.createWriteStream(req.params.file).pipe(response));
  });
});
```

This gives me an error "Cannot pipe. Not Readable". The file itself is not a regular file format (it's a file from our customized software with its own extension).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one you need to use readable stream here, not writable

The Express `res` object is derived from node's `http.ServerResponse`, which is itself implementing node's `WritableStream` interface. See docs [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res) and [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse).

Since that is the case, I think you can use `response` argument passed to your callback directly, since that is already a `ReadableStream` (see [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage)). Try using readable stream like this:

```
router.get('/download/:file', function (req, res, next) {
  http.get('http://anothersite/' + req.params.file, function(response) {
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + req.params.file);
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/octet-stream');
    response.pipe(res);  //  <-- change here
  });
});
```

This code is working, with node v5.0.0 and latest chrome:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  http.get('http://www.fillmurray.com/200/300', (response) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + 'hello.jpg');
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/octet-stream');
    response.pipe(res)
  });
});

app.listen(3001, () => console.log(('listening :)')))
```

Comment: Hi aarosil, seems like this puts [object Object] into the downloaded file instead of actually being the file. any thoughts?

Comment: Hi! If you still have more problem, can you copy/paste code where it outputs `[object Object]`? Thank you!!!

Comment: It is in the downloaded file -> if i open the file in notepad, it just says [object Object]. I'm using your code to the letter.

Comment: Sorry to hear this, maybe it has to do w/ encoding. I tried out myself and it worked, I updated my answer w/ the code in case it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use request library as:
`request('http://anothersite/').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('filename.extension'))`

**Update:**

If you are willing to do it by http you can create a write stream to as follow. After saving the file successfully I think you can do `res.download()` correctly.

```
var http = require('http')

http.get('http://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png').on('response', function (response) {
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('output.png');

    response.pipe(writeStream);

    response.on('end', function () {
        console.log('stream completed!')
    });

    // This is here incase any errors occur
    writeStream.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

});
```

Comment: Hi Tolsee, how do i respond to the http-get with the file when i use request?

Comment: You can simply pipe the get as follow:
`request
  .get('http://google.com/doodle.png')
  .on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err)
  })
  .pipe(res)`

Comment: i don't get it, I get the same issue as with the Aarosil's solution. the file downloaded is not the original file I got from the other server. it's just a text document with [object Object] in it